# React Component crashes when connecting it to redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a redux store working in other components, it has nothing strange since I have always connected the components this way.

This is the original code without any redux connected

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
import InfoPanel from "./InfoPanel.js"



export default function TablePhones(props) {
    const rows = props.phones

    function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
        if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
        return order === "desc"
            ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
            : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
    }

    function stableSort(array, comparator) {
        const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
        stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
            const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
            if (order !== 0) return order;
            return a[1] - b[1];
        });
        return stabilizedThis.map(el => el[0]);
    }

    const headCells = [
        { id: "name", numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: "Name" },
        {
            id: "manufacturer",
            numeric: false,
            disablePadding: false,
            label: "Manufacturer"
        },
        { id: "color", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Color" },
        { id: "price", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Price" },
        { id: "screen", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Screen" },
        { id: "processor", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Processor" },
        { id: "ram", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Ram" }
    ];

    function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
        const { classes, order, orderBy, onRequestSort } = props;
        const createSortHandler = property => event => {
            onRequestSort(event, property);
        };

        return (
            <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                    {headCells.map(headCell => (
                        <TableCell
                            key={headCell.id}
                            align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
                            padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
                            sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                        >
                            <TableSortLabel
                                active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                                direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
                                onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                            >
                                {headCell.label}
                                {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                                    <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                                        {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                                    </span>
                                ) : null}
                            </TableSortLabel>
                        </TableCell>
                    ))}
                </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
        );
    }

    EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
        classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        order: PropTypes.oneOf(["asc", "desc"]).isRequired,
        orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired
    };

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
        root: {
            width: "100%"
        },
        paper: {
            width: "100%",
            marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
        },
        table: {
            minWidth: 750
        },
        visuallyHidden: {
            border: 0,
            clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
            height: 1,
            margin: -1,
            overflow: "hidden",
            padding: 0,
            position: "absolute",
            top: 20,
            width: 1
        }
    }));

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [order, setOrder] = React.useState("asc");
    const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState("calories");
    const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
    const [dense] = React.useState(false);
    const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = React.useState(false)
    const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);

    const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
        const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
        setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
        setOrderBy(property);
    };



    const handleClick = (event, name, id, manufacturer, description, color, price, imageFileName, screen, processor, ram) => {
        setIsSelected(true)
        console.log(name, id, manufacturer, description, color, price, imageFileName, screen, processor, ram)


    };

    const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
        setPage(newPage);
    };

    const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
        setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
        setPage(0);
    };


    const emptyRows =
        rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);

    return (
        <div >
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                    <TableContainer>
                        <Table
                            className={classes.table}
                            aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
                            size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}
                            aria-label="enhanced table"
                        >
                            <EnhancedTableHead
                                classes={classes}
                                order={order}
                                orderBy={orderBy}
                                onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                                rowCount={rows.length}
                            />
                            <TableBody>
                                {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                                    .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                    .map((row, index) => {
                                        const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;

                                        return (
                                            <TableRow
                                                hover
                                                onClick={event => handleClick(event, row.name, row.id, row.manufacturer, row.description, row.color, row.price, row.imageFileName, row.screen, row.processor, row.ram)}
                                                role="checkbox"
                                                tabIndex={-1}
                                                key={row.name}
                                            >
                                                <TableCell
                                                    component="th"
                                                    id={labelId}
                                                    scope="row"
                                                    padding="none"
                                                >
                                                    {row.name}
                                                </TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{row.manufacturer}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{row.color}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{row.price}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{row.screen}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{row.processor}</TableCell>
                                                <TableCell align="right">{row.ram}</TableCell>
                                            </TableRow>
                                        );
                                    })}
                                {emptyRows > 0 && (
                                    <TableRow style={{ height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows }}>
                                        <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                                    </TableRow>
                                )}
                            </TableBody>
                        </Table>
                    </TableContainer>
                    <TablePagination
                        rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10]}
                        component="div"
                        count={rows.length}
                        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                        page={page}
                        onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                        onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                    />
                </Paper>
            </div>
            {isSelected ? <InfoPanel /> : <div>There is nothing selected</div>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

But then I decide to connect it and it suddenly crashes

The only thing I do is:

- 1: Renaming `export default function TablePhones` so it looks like `function TablePhones`

And i add this right in the end of the file

`export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TablePhones)`

I also add this in the beginning of th file

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return state
}
```

So it ends up looking like

```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux"
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Table from "@material-ui/core/Table";
    import TableBody from "@material-ui/core/TableBody";
    import TableCell from "@material-ui/core/TableCell";
    import TableContainer from "@material-ui/core/TableContainer";
    import TableHead from "@material-ui/core/TableHead";
    import TablePagination from "@material-ui/core/TablePagination";
    import TableRow from "@material-ui/core/TableRow";
    import TableSortLabel from "@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel";
    import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper";
    import InfoPanel from "./InfoPanel.js"
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
        return state
    }
    
    function TablePhones(props) {
        const rows = props.phones
    
        function descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy) {
            if (b[orderBy] < a[orderBy]) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (b[orderBy] > a[orderBy]) {
                return 1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    
        function getComparator(order, orderBy) {
            return order === "desc"
                ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
                : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
        }
    
        function stableSort(array, comparator) {
            const stabilizedThis = array.map((el, index) => [el, index]);
            stabilizedThis.sort((a, b) => {
                const order = comparator(a[0], b[0]);
                if (order !== 0) return order;
                return a[1] - b[1];
            });
            return stabilizedThis.map(el => el[0]);
        }
    
        const headCells = [
            { id: "name", numeric: false, disablePadding: true, label: "Name" },
            {
                id: "manufacturer",
                numeric: false,
                disablePadding: false,
                label: "Manufacturer"
            },
            { id: "color", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Color" },
            { id: "price", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Price" },
            { id: "screen", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Screen" },
            { id: "processor", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Processor" },
            { id: "ram", numeric: true, disablePadding: false, label: "Ram" }
        ];
    
        function EnhancedTableHead(props) {
            const { classes, order, orderBy, onRequestSort } = props;
            const createSortHandler = property => event => {
                onRequestSort(event, property);
            };
    
            return (
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        {headCells.map(headCell => (
                            <TableCell
                                key={headCell.id}
                                align={headCell.numeric ? "right" : "left"}
                                padding={headCell.disablePadding ? "none" : "default"}
                                sortDirection={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : false}
                            >
                                <TableSortLabel
                                    active={orderBy === headCell.id}
                                    direction={orderBy === headCell.id ? order : "asc"}
                                    onClick={createSortHandler(headCell.id)}
                                >
                                    {headCell.label}
                                    {orderBy === headCell.id ? (
                                        <span className={classes.visuallyHidden}>
                                            {order === "desc" ? "sorted descending" : "sorted ascending"}
                                        </span>
                                    ) : null}
                                </TableSortLabel>
                            </TableCell>
                        ))}
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
            );
        }
    
        EnhancedTableHead.propTypes = {
            classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
            numSelected: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
            onRequestSort: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            onSelectAllClick: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
            order: PropTypes.oneOf(["asc", "desc"]).isRequired,
            orderBy: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            rowCount: PropTypes.number.isRequired
        };
    
        const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
            root: {
                width: "100%"
            },
            paper: {
                width: "100%",
                marginBottom: theme.spacing(2)
            },
            table: {
                minWidth: 750
            },
            visuallyHidden: {
                border: 0,
                clip: "rect(0 0 0 0)",
                height: 1,
                margin: -1,
                overflow: "hidden",
                padding: 0,
                position: "absolute",
                top: 20,
                width: 1
            }
        }));
    
        const classes = useStyles();
        const [order, setOrder] = React.useState("asc");
        const [orderBy, setOrderBy] = React.useState("calories");
        const [page, setPage] = React.useState(0);
        const [dense] = React.useState(false);
        const [isSelected, setIsSelected] = React.useState(false)
        const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = React.useState(5);
    
        const handleRequestSort = (event, property) => {
            const isAsc = orderBy === property && order === "asc";
            setOrder(isAsc ? "desc" : "asc");
            setOrderBy(property);
        };
    
    
    
        const handleClick = (event, name, id, manufacturer, description, color, price, imageFileName, screen, processor, ram) => {
            setIsSelected(true)
            console.log(name, id, manufacturer, description, color, price, imageFileName, screen, processor, ram)
    
    
        };
    
        const handleChangePage = (event, newPage) => {
            setPage(newPage);
        };
    
        const handleChangeRowsPerPage = event => {
            setRowsPerPage(parseInt(event.target.value, 10));
            setPage(0);
        };
    
    
        const emptyRows =
            rowsPerPage - Math.min(rowsPerPage, rows.length - page * rowsPerPage);
    
        return (
            <div >
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <Paper className={classes.paper}>
                        <TableContainer>
                            <Table
                                className={classes.table}
                                aria-labelledby="tableTitle"
                                size={dense ? "small" : "medium"}
                                aria-label="enhanced table"
                            >
                                <EnhancedTableHead
                                    classes={classes}
                                    order={order}
                                    orderBy={orderBy}
                                    onRequestSort={handleRequestSort}
                                    rowCount={rows.length}
                                />
                                <TableBody>
                                    {stableSort(rows, getComparator(order, orderBy))
                                        .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                        .map((row, index) => {
                                            const labelId = `enhanced-table-checkbox-${index}`;
    
                                            return (
                                                <TableRow
                                                    hover
                                                    onClick={event => handleClick(event, row.name, row.id, row.manufacturer, row.description, row.color, row.price, row.imageFileName, row.screen, row.processor, row.ram)}
                                                    role="checkbox"
                                                    tabIndex={-1}
                                                    key={row.name}
                                                >
                                                    <TableCell
                                                        component="th"
                                                        id={labelId}
                                                        scope="row"
                                                        padding="none"
                                                    >
                                                        {row.name}
                                                    </TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.manufacturer}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.color}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.price}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.screen}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.processor}</TableCell>
                                                    <TableCell align="right">{row.ram}</TableCell>
                                                </TableRow>
                                            );
                                        })}
                                    {emptyRows > 0 && (
                                        <TableRow style={{ height: (dense ? 33 : 53) * emptyRows }}>
                                            <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                                        </TableRow>
                                    )}
                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                        </TableContainer>
                        <TablePagination
                            rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10]}
                            component="div"
                            count={rows.length}
                            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
                            page={page}
                            onChangePage={handleChangePage}
                            onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
                        />
                    </Paper>
                </div>
                {isSelected ? <InfoPanel /> : <div>There is nothing selected</div>}
            </div>
        );
    }
    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(TablePhones)
```

And whenever I try to load it now i get an error

> TypeError: array.map is not a function //line 40

Why is this happening, I used to connect it like that, but this makes no sense

Comment: Try to add `console.log(this.props)` after your `const mapStateToProps`. What does it show? probably the problem may be in here `return state`

Comment: @Vova props is undefined there  , but thats normal, because there are no props anywhere there, since its not inside a function

Comment: You should put `const mapStateToProps = (state) => {return state}`inside the function you connect

Comment: @Vova but then I cant export default connect the function, since the mapstatetoprops is inside the function

Comment: yes, you are right. I wonder what do you get from mapStateToProps state?

Comment: @Vova its simply this ``` let defaultState = {
    phones: { },
    isSelected : false
}
```